# Gmail messagesTotal in label data is incorrect

Tags: json, gmail-api

I am using the Gmail REST API to get data about Gmail labels.  One of the items returned is "messagesTotal".  For most of my labels, this value is correct.  But for one, I am getting a value of 0, when I am certain the label has three messages (according to the Gmail GUI).  Any idea what the problem is?  I am making the GET call like this:

https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels/Label_143

Comment: What happens if you ask it for to [*list* the messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) with that labelid?

Comment: That works fine, I see my messages.  So that would work to get a count, but it involves a lot more overhead, especially if a label has more than a trivial number of messages.  I should add, I can use the IMAP SELECT command on this folder/label, and get an accurate count, but I want to use the standard API in this case.

Comment: Does it do that for other labels for you or just that one?  Specifically other user labels and other system labels?  Is it just messagesTotal?  (are threads* and messagesUnread correct?)

Comment: So far, I have seen this problem only with one label.  As an experiment, I set the read flag to "unread" for one of the messages and checked the result.  messagesTotal is still 0, but messagesUnread is 1, as is threadsUnread.  What I was really hoping for here, is a response from Google saying "Oh, that is an obvious bug, we'll look into it right away".  Since that is a fantasy, unless somebody can suggest how I could possibly be doing this wrong, I guess I'll withdraw my question...